# how to express that 1st number must less than 2nd number in regular expression /^\d+-\d+$/

Tags: regex

I have to validate a string that two natural number joined by a hyphen
and the first number must less than second number. please tell me is this 
possible, thank you.
pattern:

```
/^\d+-\d+$/
```

it it possible to do this?

```
1-2 OK
2-1 NG
```

Comment: it won't be possible through regex only.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot do maths!!!!!!1

Comment: What's the language/tool?

Comment: Extract everything with `^(\d+)-(\d+)$` then compare `$1` and `$2` in your code.

Comment: What is the possible range of the numbers?

Comment: Thank for all the reply. I have realized that it is not possible to do mathematical computations using regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly, regex does not do mathematical computations. You will have to find another option.

Comment: @vks - "No, you can't" is a viable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. **if use php:**

```
function valid_num($a){
        $a=explode("-",$a);
        if($a[0]<$a[1]) return true;
        else return false;
    }
     valid_num("1-2");// true
     valid_num("2-1");// false
```